# Unable to show the Left view in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am unable to show the left view in the UITextField. I know this is very easy thing and has been asked many times. I have found solutions to make a custom view and to show it as a left view.

I am trying to make a UILabel that shows the country code in the text field. I made the following function but it shows the empty space only.

```
func setCountryCode(textField: UITextField){
    let viewPadding = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: Int(textField.frame.origin.x), y: Int(textField.frame.origin.y), width: width , height: Int(textField.frame.size.height)))

    viewPadding.textColor = CommonUtils.hexStringToUIColor(hex: AppColor.colorTextSecondary)
    viewPadding.text = mCallingCode
    viewPadding.font = viewPadding.font.withSize(12)
    viewPadding.textAlignment = .center

    textField.leftView = viewPadding
    textField.leftViewMode = .whileEditing
}
```

Comment: Did you actually call this method with the correct text field? I ran this in a playground and it worked fine.

Comment: yes, I am calling this with the correct textField